# Import data to Google SQL from a gsheet

Tags: sql, algorithm, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

What is the best way to import data into google sql DB from a spreadsheet file?

I have to import two file with 4k rows each into a db.

I've tried to load 4k (one file) rows using Appscript and the result was:

> Execution succeeded [294.336 seconds total runtime]

Ideas?

```
Code here
```

https://pastebin.com/3RiM1CNb

Comment: Please provide how you do it, I mean, your code here.

Comment: It would be a routine task right?

Comment: No, this files will be uploaded two times for month in gdrive. I've tried to put all the sheet into an array but when I execute the appscript, appears: "Argument too large: sql". I'm looking for something more optimized

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on how often you need this done. From your comment "No, this files will be uploaded two times for month in gdrive.", I think you mean 2 times/month.

If you need this done programmatically, I suggest to use a cronjob and have either [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) or a local machine run that cronjob.

You can access the spreadsheet with a [serviceaccount](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) (add it to the users of that spreadsheet like any other user) using [libraries](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) (check the quickstarts on the side for your language of preference) and process the data with that. How to actually process the data depends on your language of choice, but that's simply inserting rows into MySQL.

The simplest option would be to [export to CSV](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/49114) and import this into [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_a_csv_file). Note that you may need to reformat this into something Cloud SQL understands, but that depends on the source data in Google Sheets.

As for the error you're getting, you're exceeding the [max allowed runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) for App Script, which is 6 minutes...